# How to calculate a result based on or-else of many expensive computations in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Assuming I have the following pseudo-C# code:

```
TResult MyMethod()
{
    var firstTry = SomeExpensiveComputation1();
    if (firstTry.IsSuccessful) return firstTry;

    var secondTry = SomeExpensiveComputation2();
    if (secondTry.IsPartiallySuccessful)
    {
        var subTry1 = SomeExpensiveComputationOn2_1(secondTry);
        if (subTry1.IsSuccessful) return subTry1;

        var subTry1 = SomeExpensiveComputationOn2_2(secondTry);
        if (subTry1.IsSuccessful) return subTry1;
    }

    return LastExpensiveComputationThatNeverFails();
}
```

If I were to do this in F#, it'd look like this:

```
let MyMethod () =
    let firstTry = SomeExpensiveComputation1 ()
    if firstTry.IsSuccessful then firstTry else
        let secondTry = SomeExpensiveComputation2 ()
        if secondTry.IsSuccessful then
            let subTry1 = SomeExpensiveComputationOn2_1 ()
            if subTry1.IsSuccessful then subTry1 else
                let subTry2 = SomeExpensiveComputationOn2_2 ()
                if subTry2.IsSuccessful then subTry2 else LastExpensiveComputationThatNeverFails ()
        else
            LastExpensiveComputationThatNeverFails()
```

As you can see above, I had to repeat `LastExpensiveComputationThatNeverFails` twice. This doesn't have to be a method call, it can be many lines of inline computations (e.g. try to get some value from cache, if it doesn't exist calculate it.) One could refactor the code into another function, but I still don't like how the same code, even if it's just one line, has to be written twice (or more), as it leads to duplication and messy maintenance. What is the correct way to write such code in F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's fine to make `LastExpensiveComputationThatNeverFails` a local function that is called whenever the result is needed.

However, one could also change the operations to return `Option<_>` and use the built-in combinator functions.

```
let MyMethod () =
  SomeExpensiveComputation1 ()
  |> Option.orElseWith
    ( fun () -> 
        SomeExpensiveComputation2 ()
        |> Option.bind (fun _ -> SomeExpensiveComputationOn2_1 () |> Option.orElseWith SomeExpensiveComputationOn2_2)
    )
  |> Option.orElseWith LastExpensiveComputationThatNeverFails
```

`Option.orElseWith LastExpensiveComputationThatNeverFails` is only executed if the previous result is `None` which it will be upon failure.

Comment: I didn't know about that function, thanks! I'll keep the question open to see if someone thinks of something else.

Comment: In general in F# it is recommended a more ROP Style of programming rather than nested ifs: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/

Comment: Isn't a computation expression an even better way to achieve this?

Comment: If you like that style but not everyone is convinced that is always superior.